# RFC 5246 TLS 1.2: padding example mistake?

Tags: tls

From [RFC 5246](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5246.txt), page 22:

```
Example: If the block length is 8 bytes, the content length
(TLSCompressed.length) is 61 bytes, and the MAC length is 20 bytes,
then the length before padding is 82 bytes (this does not include the
IV.  Thus, the padding length modulo 8 must be equal to 6 in order to
make the total length an even multiple of 8 bytes (the block length).
The padding length can be 6, 14, 22, and so on, through 254.  If the
padding length were the minimum necessary, 6, the padding would be 6
bytes, each containing the value 6.  Thus, the last 8 octets of the
GenericBlockCipher before block encryption would be xx 06 06 06 06 06
06 06, where xx is the last octet of the MAC.
```

So, `61+20=82`, last 8 octets contains seven `06`? Did I misunderstand something? Or such important document contains mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The document is correct, `xx` is the last octet of the MAC, followed by six times the `06` octet as padding, followed by the length octet (`06`). The last length octet is not part of the padding.

See the definition of GenericBlockCipher in [section 6.2.3.2 of RFC 5246](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246.html#section-6.2.3.2):

```
struct {
    opaque IV[SecurityParameters.record_iv_length];
    block-ciphered struct {
        opaque content[TLSCompressed.length];
        opaque MAC[SecurityParameters.mac_length];
        uint8 padding[GenericBlockCipher.padding_length];
        uint8 padding_length;
    };
} GenericBlockCipher;
```

Comment: Note this differs from the padding in PKCS7/CMS (based on and often (mis)labelled as PKCS5) where the padding count/value _does_ include the last octet.